# Rewrite Rule custom index file Drupal installation

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, directoryindex

This is the current Rewrite rule of Drupal set in my htaccess file:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works well, but the problem is that I want to have a custom page which will open when people browse to the website. More specific:

www.company.com/ should open index.html
All other pages should use the default rewriterule of Drupal.

I tried editing the DirectoryIndex, but then all pages are redirected to index.html.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

I also tried adding different Rewrite Rules but I didn't have any luck yet. Htaccess is not my best skill.

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [L]
```

Probably there will be an easy solution, but I can't figure out what to do.

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the rule the 301 code, meaning permanently moved.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried adding the 301 rule but it didn't fix the problem.

This is what I have now:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com(/)?$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
  RewriteRule ^/?$ index.html [L]  

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]`
This works well, but when I go to domain.com/?q= it shows my index.html file instead of the Drupal node.